# What is the point of limiting max number of deployed Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

[It says](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) "1000 deployed functions per project" and "can not be increased". I'm not nearly close to 1000 functions, but still, why is it limited?

Answer (score 0):

Each deployed function will scale up to 1000 concurrent server instances to handle invocations for that function, as needed.

If the number of functions deployed for a project was unlimited, that would mean an unlimited number of server instances would be allocated for those unlimited number of functions.  Nobody has the kind of compute power to avoid potential abuse in that kind of situation.

**Everything** needs limits to avoid abuse.  Or at the very least, drastically unexpected billing.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Cold functions do not use "compute power", they take up storage space and storing source code, docker images to be precise, is relatively cheap.

AWS and Azure prove that it's possible, by allowing an unlimited number of functions.

Comment: To be fair, even storage space has a limit, so they probably have mechanisms in place to prevent abuse once you ge over an unrealistic number of functions.

Comment: I might have misunderstood this answer, as it seems you're referring to the computing resources that are used to handle invocation requests and not the execution of the lambda's source code itself. Nevertheless, I believe that the OPs question was not answered, as it is evidently feasible, both technically and financially, to allow a quasi-unlimited number of serverless functions.

Comment: Imagine a scenario where someone deploys nearly infinite number of functions, then attempts to scale them all up to the max load they can each handle.  That's too much compute power to allow to one project.  The limit is to prevent abuse of Google resources. 1000 deployed functions is more than enough for practical use, but caps the total liability on the resources that could possibly be consumed by the project. @SamBokai

Comment: There are legitimate use cases where 1000 functions are not near enough. Vercel's deployment product for example, deploys your projects via lambda functions and they are hosting many thousands of projects. I think this whole question is more of a business problem than a technical one. As long as the cloud provider bills the user appropriately, I don't see a problem with a large amount of functions.

Comment: @SamBokai You're free to choose the product that best meets your needs.  If you find Cloud Functions limitations problematic, then I don't recommend that you use it.  All I can really say here are the facts, and those facts are given context by the further fact that I used to work on the Firebase team on this very product.